# Making a Photo Hunt Game using Javascript and HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5, browser-based-games

I am looking for a way to make a photo hunt game using HTML5 and Javascript. Where should I start after the images. And How would I make clickable areas on the image, using javascript? 
If you know of any examples that would help or are willing to help let me know, please.
Thank You

Comment: You could either take 2 different images, and seek for different pixels, and then seek for all different pixels in a group, that is find a group of pixels, where each 'changed' pixel is not further than 5 pixels from the rest. This could be quite complicated and CPU intensive, so you could also just store coordinates of differences in some XML file.

Comment: This isn't a gamedev-specific question; it's just a general programming question, so it's off topic here and belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Questions about *"how to make (or start making) a particular type of game"* are considered off-topic here (have a look at the [FAQ]).

Comment: @bummzack As I understand it, the question is about not a game as a whole, but main algorithm of dealing with images differences. For example how would one define the place of a difference in XML, as a group of pixels, a path around the place, or just a point in center? This question is definitely answerable, though it's form is not best.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I think the OP should clarify the question a bit more. As it is now it is too broad and off topic. Basically the same as this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19365

Comment: This question is vague (what is a "photo hunt" game?) and broad. You should define what you want, break it down into the pieces you need (you gave a couple of examples), and then work on those pieces and ask specific, answerable questions here if you have trouble. In any case, please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

To create Photo Hunt Game using Javascript and HTML5, You should have good knowledge on

**hidden object**

- http://www.gamedev.net/topic/628780-creating-a-hidden-object-game-in-html5-pseudo-code/
- http://efreedom.com/Question/4-19365/HTML-Javascript-Hidden-Object-Photo-Hunt-Game
- http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/hidden.html
- http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/client-object-property-method/hidden.php
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/hidden.shtml
- http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javahidden.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532401/hidden-object-but-still-have-a-place-reserved

**tag map**

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp
- http://blog.xrtml.org/post/an-introduction-to-the-map-tag_326.html
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml
- http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t917212-javascript-popup-using-html-map-tag.html

**How to preload image**

- http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript/
- http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317
- http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/image/preload.html
- http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

**Further, You have to choose a better JavaScript Library or Game Engine to develop you game**

- [What are good JS libraries for game dev?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/what-are-good-js-libraries-for-game-dev)

Comment: -1. This is just a bunch of links and not really an answer. Also the links about hiding a form or input elements are kinda out of place. I would never use a hidden form for a HTML5 photo-hunt game.

Comment: @bummzack, Thanks for -1. I have learned from you. I don't want point, rather I am willing to learn and share the right one. Please help me improve my answer. :)

Comment: @bummzack, As your comment, I have removed hidden form and hidden value. (I thought that those may help him). And now what should i include to this answer? Please help me to improve my answer.

Comment: The question itself is not really answerable and off-topic so it's hard to tell how to improve your answer. I removed the downvote since you removed the links that are plainly misleading.